# Slicing object in several pieces

Tags: modeling

So lets say I have a cube with length of 6 and I would like to slice it in 4 pieces, leaving me with 4 cubes with length of 1.5 each. I am aware that I can do that with knife tool, but how to slice cube in exact 4 pieces?

Is that possible with Blender?

UPDATE:

Slicing with Loop Cut and Slide as will work on normal cube, but in case geometry is a bit complex, it will not work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to the edit mode

Hit the **Loop Cut and Slide** as shown in the picture below

Hover over on cube and wait for the line appear, move pointer to switch between, horizontal and vertical edges,

scroll your mouse wheel two times to increase the number of cuts to 3, hit enter or double click to finalized it.

You will get your required result.

As shown in the image below:

[image]

---

Here is the solution based on your updates

1. Add a plane on the top of your cube, slightly bigger than your cube, go to the edit mode and add 3 loop cuts on the plane
2. Hit A to select all faces of the plane, hit x and delete only face, so that we have only a grid of edges, as shown below:
   [image]
3. Select the plane and then your cube (in order), enter edit mode, go to top view (numpad 7), make sure you are in orthographic mode
4. Hit "knife project" and check the box "Cut Through"

[image]

6. Go to object view and select your cube and edit mode you will get the same loop cuts as you did in your plane, delete the plane for the clean up

I hope it worked for you :)

---

As per your updates

[image]
These edges are not seems to be required.

Comment: Thank you, it works with cube, but can you see my updated question? On a picture attached unfortunately it will not work

Comment: I will try to give alternatives based on your updates, Thank you

Comment: Please take a look of updated solution, if worked please accept the answer!

Comment: Nice. It works! Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: I would like to notice that step 1 can be done also with subdividing the surface by selecting the opposite edges x2. You could add that to your answer.

Comment: I am glad it worked, Please take a look of updated answer, about subdividing.